# Can't implicity convert type 'string' error

Tags: c#, linq

I updated my code this but I always get a '0' value for REQ_INSP_APPROVAL field regardless. When a name should be value of 1 for that field and it still shows as 0:

```
        W_USER usr = new W_USER
        {
            Name = Convert.ToString(dgvMaster.CurrentRow.Cells   [dgvMaster.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value)
        };
        //WINS_USER usr = Convert.ToString(o);
        //IQueryable<WINS_USER> users = dc.CMB_USERs;
        showLegend = loadedReports.Where(f => f.form.EXEMPTFROMIP == 0 && f.form.FORMHEADER.INSPAPPROVALPROCESS == 1 && f.form.SUPERAPPROVED == 1 && usr.REQ_INSP_APPROVAL == 1).Count() > 0;I updated the code to this: 

if (dgvMaster.CurrentRow == null) 
    return;

object o = dgvMaster.CurrentRow.Cells[dgvMaster.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value;

// Error on the following line
W_USER usr = Convert.ToString(dgvMaster.CurrentRow.Cells[dgvMaster.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value);
showLegend = loadedReports.Where(f => f.form.EXEMPTFROMIP == 0 &&
                                      f.form.FORMHEADER.INSPAPPROVALPROCESS == 1 &&
                                      f.form.SUPERAPPROVED == 1 &&
                                      usr.REQ_INSP_APPROVAL == 1)
                          .Count() > 0;
```

Also in my designer class file I updated the REQ_INSP_APPROVAL from this

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_REQ_INSP_APPROVAL", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> REQ_INSP_APPROVAL
    {
        get
        {
            return this._REQ_INSP_APPROVAL;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._REQ_INSP_APPROVAL != value))
            {
                this.OnREQ_INSP_APPROVALChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._REQ_INSP_APPROVAL = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("REQ_INSP_APPROVAL");
                this.OnREQ_INSP_APPROVALChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

to

```
            [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_REQ_INSP_APPROVAL", DbType="Int")]
    public int REQ_INSP_APPROVAL
    {
        get
        {
            return this._REQ_INSP_APPROVAL;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._REQ_INSP_APPROVAL != value))
            {
                this.OnREQ_INSP_APPROVALChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._REQ_INSP_APPROVAL = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("REQ_INSP_APPROVAL");
                this.OnREQ_INSP_APPROVALChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Before updating I was getting null for the REQ_INSP_APPROVAL now I'm getting as I stated '0'.

I know this is a lot but I really need help.

Comment: How is W_USER defined?

Comment: It's defined as a class?? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: You're trying to assign a value of type `string` to a variable that isn't of type `string`.

Comment: `W_USER` definitely looks like a custom type. If that's the case, the error is clear: you are trying to put a `string` into a `W_USER`. The compiler doesn't know how to do that.

Comment: just like this "usr.REQ_INSP_APPROVAL" there has to be a property in your W_USER class do a "usr." to see propertie and assign value to the one that you need, Also side note, you are creating a new object usr not sure how usr.REQ_INSP_APPROVAL will be 1 in the linq immediately following your error

Comment: use var usr.Name = Convert.ToString(dgvMaster.CurrentRow.Cells[dgvMaster.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value);

Answer (score 0):

What is W_USER? Seems like W_USER is a class and you are trying to store a string value in the object of the class. That's why it is throwing you error. store below in a string variable.

```
     W_USER usr=new W_USER();   usr.Name=Convert.ToString(dgvMaster.CurrentRow.Cells[dgvMaster.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value);
```

Comment: W_USER is a database table. It's called from a partial class in another class file. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: You can't store a string value in that. Either you need to store that in a string variable. can you post the definition of W_USER here?

Comment: I'm to  get the value for usr.REQ_INSP_APPROVAL in the linq statement and I have to pull from that W_USER table to get it when I click on the row in the datagrid. One of the columns is the name so when I get that name I want it to set the record from that W_USER table which has REQ_INSP_APPROVAL as one of the fields. Trying to explain this the best I can.

Comment: Posted definition in original post

Comment: edited my response. Please check. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: Garauv,this is closer but I get nulls on all of the fields in W_USER. When I debug and click on the Results View REQ_INS_APPROVAL and most of the other fields in that table all say null. That field should either be a 0 or 1 value. I think when W_USER usr = new W_USER(); and sets everything to null.

Comment: Gaurav, it is there now.

Comment: Not quite, I need more assistance. Please see my original post. I updated the code.

Comment: Asking for more assistance on updated code in my original post. Please review. I would appreciate it.